# Leer caracteres repetidos

Tags: java

necesito hacer un código donde lea un texto o caracteres que yo ingrese
me diga cual es el que mas se repite
ya tengo mi código me lee los caracteres pero a la hora de decir cual es el que mas se repite se revienta

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

   Scanner lector=new Scanner(System.in);
   String cadena= "";
   char [] Arraycadena;
   char caracter;
   int contador =0;
   System.out.println("escriba una frase");
   cadena=lector.nextLine();
   Arraycadena = cadena.toCharArray();
   for(int i=0; i<Arraycadena.length; i++){

       caracter = Arraycadena[i];
         for (int j =0; j<Arraycadena.length; j++){
               if (Arraycadena [j]== caracter){

                  contador++;
               }
         }
   }

   //aca me imprime cada letra con las respctivas veces que se ha contado
    System.out.println(+contador);
     contador=0;


}
```

---

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

   Scanner lector=new Scanner(System.in);
   String cadena= "";
   char [] Arraycadena;
   char caracter;
   int contador =0;
   System.out.println("escriba una frase");
   cadena=lector.nextLine();
   Arraycadena = cadena.toCharArray();
   for(int i=0; i<Arraycadena.length; i++){

       caracter = Arraycadena[i];
         for (int j =0; j<Arraycadena.length; j++){
               if (Arraycadena [j]== caracter){

                  contador++;
               }
         }
        }

// aca me imprime cada letra con las respctivas veces que se ha contado
    System.out.println(+contador);
     contador=0;


    }

}
```

Comment: Mira esta [guia](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: donde es que revienta?? con que error?

Comment: Haciendo uso de `Streams` , se evitan tantos ciclos y demás. :)

Answer (score 2):

Estás llamando incorrectamente la variable contador al mostrarla. Tienes que llamarla `System.out.println(contador);` no `System.out.println(+contador);`.

Además, debes de ir guardando la letra que lleva más repeticiones e ir verificando si aparece otra letra con más repeticiones.

El código sería algo así:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner lector = new Scanner(System.in);
    String texto = "";
    char [] letras;

    int mayorRepeticion = 0;
    char letraMasRepetida;

    System.out.println("Escribe una frase: ");

    texto = lector.nextLine();
    letras = texto.toCharArray();

    for(int i=0; i<letras.length; i++){

        char letraActual = letras[i];
        int contador = 0;

        for (int j =0; j<letras.length; j++){
            if (letras[j] == letraActual)
                contador++;
        }

        if(mayorRepeticion < contador)
        {
            mayorRepeticion = contador
            letraMasRepetida = letraActual;
        }
    }

    System.out.println(letraMasRepetida+": Se repite "+mayorRepeticion);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Scanner lector = new Scanner(System.in);
 System.out.println("escriba una frase");
 String cadena = lector.nextLine();
 int contador = 0;
 char caracter = 0;

 while (cadena.length() != 0) { // mientras la cadena tenga algún carácter la recorremos
     int contadorAux = 0;
     for (int j = 0; j < cadena.length(); j++) { // recorremos la cadena para contar los caracteres del indice cero
         if (cadena.charAt(0) == cadena.charAt(j)) {
             contadorAux++;
         }
     }

     if (contadorAux > contador) { // si el contador del nuevo caracter es mayor al que ya estaba guardado, lo cambiamos
         contador = contadorAux;
         caracter = cadena.charAt(0);
     }

     // borramos los carácteres contados para ahorrar entrar mas veces para contarlos otra vez
     cadena = cadena.replaceAll(cadena.charAt(0) + "", "");
 }
 System.out.println(caracter + ": " + contador);
```

Comment: Los comentarios en el código están bien, pero también estaría bueno que explicaras por fuera del código, cuál fue tu idea principal para resolver el problema, y cuáles fueron las modificaciones al código para llegar a eso.